In SLA4031 (a darlington pair) what’s the function of R1 and R2
Hello I’m new in the electronics field and i stumbled across this IC SLA4031
Which is a darlington and k wanted to know what’s the function of the 2 diodes at the collector and the function of R1 and R2.
Thanks in advance

The resistors are to reduce the effects of leakage current, increase turn-off speed, and ensure the bases aren't floating.
The diodes are for transient protection when switching inductive loads. Pin 3 in the diagram would be connected to the load's positive supply, so for instance with a relay this would connect the diode across the coil the way a typical spike diode would be.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
